# Apache Spark not using partition information from Hive partitioned external table

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a simple Hive-External table which is created on top of S3 (Files are in CSV format). When I run the hive query it shows all records and partitions.

However when I use the same table in Spark ( where the Spark SQL has a where condition on the partition column) it does not show that a partition filter is applied. However for a Hive Managed table , Spark is able to use the information of partitions and apply the partition filter.

Is there any flag or setting that can help me make use of partitions of Hive external tables in Spark ? Thanks.

[image]
[image]

[image]

**Update :**

For some reason, only the spark plan is not showing the Partition Filters. However, when you look at the data loaded its only loading the data needed from the partitions.

Ex: Where rating=0 , loads only one file of 1 MB, when I don't have filter its reads all 3 partition for 3 MB

[image]

[image]

Comment: what happens if you replace "where movieid in (10,12)" with "where rating=0" in the query to hive-managed table? I have a suspicion that "PartitionFilters: ..." will disappear in that case. Probably the filter is not invoked if you include only a specific partition in "where" clause

Comment: ah, the partition in hive-managed table is "movieid", not "rating", right? my reasoning was wrong then

Comment: @mangusta I understand the confusion will update the question with details

Comment: Can you try where clause value as string instead int - like where rating=‘0’

Comment: A little unclear here

Answer (score 2):

tl; dr set the following before the running sql for external table
`spark.sql("set spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreOrc=true")`

The difference in behaviour is not because of extenal/managed table.
The behaviour depends on two factors
1. Where the table was created(Hive or Spark)
2. File format (I believe it is ORC in this case, from the screen capture)

### Where the table was created(Hive or Spark)

If the table was create using Spark APIs, it is considered as Datasource table.
If the table was created usng HiveQL, it is considered as Hive native table.
The metadata of both these tables are store in Hive metastore, the only difference is in the `provider` field of `TBLPROPERTIES` of the tables(`describe extended <tblName>`). The value of the property is `orc`or empty in Spark table and `hive` for a Hive.

#### How spark uses this information

When provider is not `hive`(datasource table), Spark uses its native way of processing the data.
If provider is `hive`, Spark uses Hive code to process the data.

### Fileformat

Spark gives config flag to instruct the engine to use Datasource way of processing the data for the floowing file formats = `Orc` and `Parquet`
Flags:

#### `Orc`

```
  val CONVERT_METASTORE_ORC = buildConf("spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreOrc")
    .doc("When set to true, the built-in ORC reader and writer are used to process " +
      "ORC tables created by using the HiveQL syntax, instead of Hive serde.")
    .booleanConf
    .createWithDefault(true)
```

#### `Parquet`

```
val CONVERT_METASTORE_PARQUET = buildConf("spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet")
    .doc("When set to true, the built-in Parquet reader and writer are used to process " +
      "parquet tables created by using the HiveQL syntax, instead of Hive serde.")
    .booleanConf
    .createWithDefault(true)
```

Comment: you could identify if Spark is considering it a  hive table or not by looking into plan - If the scan node is HiveTableRelation(first snippet), Spark will process using Hive flow, otherwsie it is a Spark datasource table

Comment: In Spark, Hive code flow gets triggered only for orc and parquet. for all other formats, Spark uses its native code for processing

Comment: @DaRkMaN the spark plan is not showing the partition filters , however when you see the Spark-UI you can see executor only loads the data as needed. Please see the updated question with more images.

Comment: How do you see it is ORC?

Comment: screen capture showing the plans has it (titled `partition-demo`)

Comment: well, I checked for ORC & parquet external partitioned table and they are able to prune the partitions as expected. just not sure whether it's scanning all the partitions in text format partitioned table. there's no clear information in plan in case of text format external partitioned table

Comment: We can use Spark UI to test this. Run without filter and with filter, the input field of the job that read data, in Spark UI will show different numbers if partition pruning had happened(it will be lesser in the query with filter). I think partition pruning happens irrespective of file formats and the way it is created(External/managed)

Answer (score -1):

I also ran into this kind of problem having multiple joins of internal and external tables.

None of the tricks work including：

```
    spark.sql("set spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet=false")
    spark.sql("set spark.sql.hive.metastorePartitionPruning=true")
    spark.sql("set spark.sql.hive.caseSensitiveInferenceMode=NEVER_INFER")
```

anyone who knows how to solve this problem.

Comment: did some tests, external table is not the reason.